# Is there any way to track how many times a Solr search result is returned?

Tags: search, solr, search-engine, lucene

We are using a Solr 4.0 server to allow our users to do a google like search of our data, return objects are of type "Item".  Does solr/lucene have anything available that can track how often a particular Item has been returned?

Yes, I have googled this with no luck at all.

Comment: I don't know of anything in Solr to do this, and it is generally not designed to make changes based on reads. However, you could write a tool to scrape the Solr log files for queries, and aggregate how many of them match a given item, but that will only catch the "current" state of the data.

Comment: our current thought is that we pull answers back into a java servlet and from there update a database table for the search terms & count.  We're looking for something in solr that could increment a field in solr so we could pull all data from solr instead of hitting the DB all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This certainly isn't the most elegant approach but with no other options I've implemented my own tracking.  I just built code to spin a thread off to count the results and keep track in the DB.

If someone runs into this issue and has a better solution please post your approach.

Comment: Do you get any idea how to track real time search query.?

Answer (score 0):

You could try attaching a [transformer](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters) but instead of manipulating the document just record the count somewhere. [Base class](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/response/transform/DocTransformer.java) is already provided, it should be really easy to extend.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how this would work, the link you provided for "transformer" takes me to the solr CommonQueryParameter page.  Could you elaborate on your answer at all?

Comment: CommonQueryParameter wiki entry has a Transformers chapter (7.3). My knowledge ends there as I have never worked with transformers, however, according to the definition they have seemed like a decent fit for your scenario.